# Efficient calculation on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to make my code faster. The problem is very simple, but I'm not finding a good way to make the calculation without looping through the whole DataFrame.

I've got three dataFrames: A, B and C.

A and B have 3 columns each, and the following format:

A (10 rows):

```
     Canal Gerencia grad
0    'ABC'   'DEF'   23
etc...
```

B (25 rows):

```
     Marca  Formato  grad
0    'GHI'   'JKL'    43
etc...
```

DataFrame C, on the other hand, has 5 columns:

C (5000 rows):

```
     Marca  Formato  Canal  Gerencia  grad
0    'GHI'   'JKL'    'ABC'   'DEF'   -102
etc...
```

I need a vector with the same length of DataFrame 'C' that adds up the values of 'grad' from the three tables, for example:

```
m = 'GHI'
f = 'JKL'
c = 'ABC'
g = 'DEF'
res = C['grad'][C['Marca']==m][C['Formato']==f][C['Canal']==c][C['Gerencia']==g] + A['grad'][A['Canal']==c][A['Gerencia']==g] + B['grad'][B['Formato']==f][B['Marca']==m]
>>-36
```

I tried looping through the C dataFrame, but is too slow. I understand I should try to avoid the loop through the dataFrame, but don't know how to do this. My actual code is the following (works, but VERY slow):

```
res=[]
for row_index, row in C.iterrows():
    vec1 = A['Gerencia']==row['Gerencia']
    vec2 = A['Canal']==row['Canal']
    vec3 = B['Marca']==row['Marca']
    vec4 = B['Formato']==row['Formato']
    grad = row['grad']
    res.append(grad + sum(A['grad'][vec1][vec2])+ sum(B['grad'][vec3][vec4]))
```

I would really appreciate any help on making this routine quicker. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you need to merge `C` with `A`:

```
C = pd.merge(C, A, on=['Canal', 'Gerencia'])
```

(this will add a column to it) and then merge the result with `B`:

```
C = pd.merge(C, B, on=['Marca', 'Formato'])
```

(again adding a column to `C`)

At this point, check `C` for the names of the columns; say they are `grad_foo`, `grad_bar`, `grad_baz`. So just add them

```
C.grad_foo + C.grad_bar + C.grad_baz
```